# Preventing Core Dump from initializing string with null pointer

Tags: c++, string, language-lawyer, stdstring, initialization-list

In my code, I have a constructor that initializes `std::string` variables from a structure containing `char *` pointers.  I'm getting Aborts with Visual Studio 2008 in the constructor, if a structure field is null.

```
class Ingredient
{
  public:
    struct Static_Table
    {
       char const * const title;
       char const * const category;
    };
    Ingredient(const Static_Table& entry)
       : m_title(entry.title),
         m_category(entry.category)
    { ; }
  private:
    std::string m_title;
    std::string m_variety;
};
```

If I have an instance of the `Static_Table` where a member is NULL, the `Ingredient` constructor *blows up*:

```
Ingredient::Static_Table test_data =
{
  /* Title */ "Pepperoni",
  /* Category */ 0, // Oops, forgot to put a string literal here.
};
Ingredient pepperoni(test_data); // This will cause Abort / Stack Dump
```

The basis of the issue is that behavior is undefined when the `char` pointer is null *(from [basic_string definition on CppReference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)*:

> Constructs the string with the contents initialized with a copy of the null-terminated character string pointed to by s. The length of the string is determined by the first null character. The behavior is undefined if s does not point at an array of at least Traits::length(s)+1 elements of CharT.

This can be verified by the simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>

int main(void)
{
    char const * const pointer = NULL;
    std::string test_string(pointer);
    std::cout << "Pointer: " << pointer << "\n";
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### My Questions:

1. Is there any method to prevent the abort / crash when using
   *initialization list* for the constructor?
2. Why can't `std::string` simply construct empty as if no parameters
   were given?

### Tool Information:

Using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows Vista.
Simple example compiled with G++ 3.4.4 using Cygwin.

Comment: Is there a reason your structure doesn't contain `std::string` to begin with?

Comment: Yes, I'm a firm believer in constant data so that I can place it into read-only memory.  The `std::string` type can't be constant data (which would be placed in a read-only data segment).  The `std::string` needs to be initialized specially at startup (versus direct access or copying with character/string literals).

Comment: To address your second question, there is no reason why it can't. However, the STL, where `std::string` originated from, has a heavy emphasis on efficiency, so even the null-pointer check that isn't even necessary in any properly written (yes, my opinion thereof ;) ) program is avoided.

Comment: May `std::string` have a reference member, which is initialized (without unnecessary `nullptr` check mentioned by Ulrich) with a result of the indirection through the pointer passed to the constructor? Then its storage could be optimized away, though I do not know about other data members of `std::string`.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question you could use the ternary operator to check for the null-pointer:

```
Ingredient(const Static_Table& entry)
    : m_title(entry.title ? entry.title : ""),
      m_category(entry.category ? entry.category : "")
{}
```